# Prove that E[x^n] >= (EX)^n for n = 2k

Tags: mathematical-statistics, probability-calculus

Prove that $E[x^n] \geq (Ex)^n$ for $n = 2k$

I only have the formula of E(x) but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Can you use Jensen’s inequality?

Comment: Maybe you can try mathematical induction?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: 1. Prove that all power functions of the type $f(x) = x^n ,n \epsilon N$ are convex functions.
2. Use Jensen’s inequality as pointed out by Dave

Answer (score 1):

First recall that $\text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$ and that $\text{Var}(X) \geq 0$.

So $\mathbb{E}[X^{2k}] = \mathbb{E}[(X^k)^2] = \text{Var}(X^k) + \mathbb{E}[X^k]^2.$

Since $\text{Var}(X^k) \geq 0$, $\, \, \, \, \mathbb{E}[X^{2k}] \geq \mathbb{E}[X^k]^2$

Edit: Just realised this doesn't answer your question. This only works when $n$ is a power of 2 (by repeating the argument multiple times). It doesn't work for all even $n$

Comment: Why does this not work for all even (positive) $n$?  Perhaps you are contemplating an inductive argument, but there are other approaches.  For instance, $n$ needn't be integral at all: you should be analyzing $|X|$ rather than $X.$  The only reason in the question to write $2k$ was to make it so that $X^{2k}=|X|^{2k}.$